# Symfony2: catch fatal ClassNotFoundException

Tags: symfony, exception, try-catch

In order to improve the cache generation in my Symfony2 project, I want to go through all php classes (even vendor) and pre-generate annotation (because for few actions, it takes up to 5 sec on the first access).

Do achieve it, I built a cache warmer to read all php classes of my projet, do a reflection class with each one and then call the annotation_reader service on the class / its methods / its properties.

This works fine with my classes, but with vendor their might be errors that I want to catch: indeed I cannot correct all vendor... The error that vendor might throw is a ClassNotFoundException which is fatal (eg. in Doctrine/DataFixtures/ContainerAwareLoader).

I just want to catch these errors (this is not a good practices, but this is only executed once so it's ok), but usual catching don't work as this is fatak. Any idea how to do it?

Comment: The standard cache warmer doesn't work ?

Comment: It doesn't generate all annotations. Or when I access a page it tries to generate the annotation of php classes where it shouldn't, maybe...

Comment: I suppose you are using windows..

Comment: That was esay to know because we don't have these kind of problems on nix systems. To be honest even you succeed correcting your issue, it will be a dirty hack. Try using a VM may be.

Comment: No problem with a dirty hack until it works...